# Get first and last time for every day using SQL query

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have this data in database:

```
musterid | musterdate          |  userid  | status
---------+---------------------+----------+-------
69       | 2017-09-01 11:58:37 |   50     |   1             
70       | 2017-09-01 12:00:07 |   50     |   1             
71       | 2017-09-01 12:29:15 |   50     |   1     
72       | 2017-09-01 12:31:15 |   50     |   1     
73       | 2017-09-01 09:58:37 |   51     |   1             
74       | 2017-09-01 11:00:07 |   51     |   1             
75       | 2017-09-01 12:29:15 |   51     |   1     
76       | 2017-09-01 07:31:15 |   51     |   1
```

I want output like this :

```
musterid | musterdate          |  userid  | status
---------+---------------------+----------+-------
69       | 2017-09-01 11:58:37 |   50     |   1      
72       | 2017-09-01 12:31:15 |   50     |   1 
73       | 2017-09-01 09:58:37 |   51     |   1 
76       | 2017-09-01 07:31:15 |   51     |   1
```

I.e. I want to get the first and last entry time for each user.

How to achieve this?

I don't know how to create a table to represent a data, so sorry for my presentation.

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?  Please post what you have tried..

Comment: the line `73 | 2017-09-01 09:58:37 | 51 | 1 ` is incorrect in your output, it should be  `75 | 2017-09-01 12:29:15 | 51 | 1` as last time

Comment: musterid 73 is entrytime for user 51 and musterid 76 is lastime for user 51.

Answer (score 0):

Complex query to get "*first and last entry time for each user*":

```
SELECT 
    t1.*
FROM
    yourtable t1
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MIN(musterdate) AS min_mdate,
        MAX(musterdate) AS max_mdate,
        userid
    FROM
        yourtable
    GROUP BY userid) t2 ON t1.userid = t2.userid
WHERE
    t1.userid = t2.userid
    AND t1.musterdate IN (t2.min_mdate , t2.max_mdate)
ORDER BY userid , musterdate;
```

Comment: It returns only last max time, is there any way to get first and last time of same date?

Comment: @MK3007, I've tested this query on your input dataset and it works fine